# I need to sign custom kernel with drm sony keys

Tags: android, sony

I am trying to make custom roms and custom kernels run but in order to do that they have to have the signing keys from sony and have to have the program required to sign them as well. Is there any way you guys can help me? This would allow custom kernel and custom roms to run on devices with Bootloader Unlock Allowed: NO. and would bring more support and devlopers as well as customers to sony:)

Comment: This, for obvious reasons is quite pretentious and borderline impossible.

Answer (score 0):

This is against the carrier-OEM legislation.
Currently, OEM's allow bootloader unlock on generic devices only.